# excluding heatmaply row_side_colors

Tags: r, heatmaply

I'm trying to make a basic heatmap in **RStudio** using *heatmaply*. My data look like this:

[image]

I tried these commands:

```r
eg <- read.delim(file="example_heatmap.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
heatmaply(
    file="heatmap_eg.png",
    height=2000, 
    eg, 
    colors=colorRampPalette(colors=c("lightblue", "darkblue")), 
    column_text_angle = 45, 
    plot_method = "plotly",
    key.title = "Ab", 
    labRow = eg[,1]
)
```

The output:

[image]

Now, in the output figure, I don't want the color bars at each row. I tried different options but couldn't get rid of the color bars from the rows. I want my output like the following one:

[image]

Please help.
All your feedbacks are highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Alvee

Comment: Hey - just to verify - you want to not have the color legend? (could you provide an image, which you changed manually in paint, that should what you want the output to be?)

Comment: Can you please post this as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?